# .cn1lib in another codename one library

Tags: codenameone

I am having several projects that share my own common cn1lib.

Now I want to extend functionality and want to add SQLite support, for that I want to add CN1data access library in my library, instead of adding it in all individual projects.

I followed the answer given in this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/N_2eq6eEgIc

But I didn't get what exactly I have to do/how to add. Can I have some example or more detail, please.

Thanks,
Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this blog post on [nesting cn1libs](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-nest-cn1libs-cross-dependencies.html). It's just a matter of editing the classpath for the cn1lib that will include the other cn1lib.